# Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/logo')

Tags: android, xml, mobile, authentication

I am developing a login screen for an app that I am working on at the moment.
But when I tried to put a few lines in login.xml, I got this error:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcePS.png)

That happened when I put the following lines in login.xml:

[The line that gives me the error has been pointed out with a red arrow.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EUD2.png)

I hope that someone can help with this issue, because I have been googling for a few hours and I checked the lines for errors but I can't find any.

Note: I am quite new to programming an app, so there might be a few mistakes in the code.

Comment: do you have a drawable by the name logo in drawable folder? you have `Logo` L caps should it be `logo`

Comment: clean you project and then check if there is a Logo file in any of the drawable folders

Comment: I placed a picture in the folder 'res' ->'drawable hdpi' but it is giving me a lot of errors at the moment, also on the other two, unused app.